# Что делать, если не работает burger menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

у меня не работает burger menu, в чём может быть проблема?
[Код](https://jsfiddle.net/Belzer/x1jhgn0v/)

```js
let menuBtn = document.querySelector('.header-btn');
let menu = document.querySelector('.header');

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  menuBtn.classList.toggle('active');
  menu.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```css
.header {
  background: #aaa;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px;
}

.header-section {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #FFEFBA;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
}

.header-logo {
  font-size: 18px;
}

header.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}


/* Гамбургер иконка */

.header-btn {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-btn span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.header-btn span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.header-btn span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: calc(50% + 5px);
}


/* Меняем гамбургер иконку, когда меню открыто */

.header-btn.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

.header-btn.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
}

.header-btn.active span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header-btn">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <section class="header-section">
      <div class="header-logo">
        Belzer<br>Design
      </div>
      <div class="header-item"><a href="">Главная</a></div>
      <div class="header-item"><a href="#product">Цены</a></div>
      <div class="header-item"><a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></div>
      <div class="header-item"><a href="#order">О заказе</a></div>
      <div class="header-item"><a href="#buy">Об оплате</a></div>
      <div class="header-item"><a href="#about">О нас</a></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код совершенно неправильный

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu')
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger')

hamburger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    menu.classList.toggle('active')
    hamburger.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
}

li{
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
a{color: white;}

.menu{
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: 0.7s;
}

.menu.active{
    left: 0;
}

.hamburger{
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.bar{
    margin: 5px auto;
    background-color: red;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2){
    opacity: 0;
}
.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1){
    transform: translateY(8px)rotate(45deg);
}
.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3){
    transform: translateY(-8px)rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#">Главная</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#">Цены</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#">Портфолио</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#">О заказе</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#">Об оплате</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#">О нас</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hamburger">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, что там у вас за меню, не отображается оно, так что вот вам другой бургер.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/pilaton/pen/VwMdxey)

```js
let paperMenu = {
  $window: $('#paper-window'),
  $paperFront: $('#paper-front'),
  $hamburger: $('.hamburger'),
  offset: 1800,
  pageHeight: $('#paper-front').outerHeight(),

  open: function() {
    this.$window.addClass('tilt');
    this.$hamburger.off('click');
    $('#container, .hamburger').on('click', this.close.bind(this));
    this.hamburgerFix(true);

  },
  close: function() {
    this.$window.removeClass('tilt');
    $('#container, .hamburger').off('click');
    this.$hamburger.on('click', this.open.bind(this));
    this.hamburgerFix(false);

  },
  updateTransformOrigin: function() {
    scrollTop = this.$window.scrollTop();
    equation = (scrollTop + this.offset) / this.pageHeight * 100;
    this.$paperFront.css('transform-origin', 'center ' + equation + '%');
  },

  hamburgerFix: function(opening) {
    if (opening) {
      $('.hamburger').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: this.$window.scrollTop() + 30 + 'px'
      });
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.hamburger').css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: '30px'
        });
      }, 300);
    }
  },
  bindEvents: function() {
    this.$hamburger.on('click', this.open.bind(this));
    $('.close').on('click', this.close.bind(this));
    this.$window.on('scroll', this.updateTransformOrigin.bind(this));
  },
  init: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
    this.updateTransformOrigin();
  },
};

paperMenu.init();
```

```css
#paper-back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #243040;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 33px;
}

#paper-back nav {
  padding: 120px 34px;
}

#paper-back nav a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

#paper-window {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 2;
}

#paper-window.tilt {
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#paper-window.tilt #paper-front {
  transform: rotate(10deg) translateZ(0);
}

#paper-front {
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transform-origin: center 70%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#container section {
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}

#container section:first-of-type {
  padding-top: 10vh;
}

#container section:first-of-type h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
}

#container section:first-of-type p {
  font-size: 25px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #container section:first-of-type {
    padding-top: 15vh;
  }
  #container section:first-of-type h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  #container section:first-of-type p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

#container section:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: #edf1f5;
}

.hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.hamburger span {
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger span,
.hamburger span:before,
.hamburger span:after {
  display: block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #243040;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.hamburger span:before,
.hamburger span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.hamburger span:before {
  bottom: -14px;
}

.hamburger span:after {
  bottom: -28px;
}

.close {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:before,
.close:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 6px;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.close:before {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.close:after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="paper-back">
  <nav>
    <div class="close"></div>
    <a href="">Главная</a>
    <a href="#product">Цены</a>
    <a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a>
    <a href="#order">О заказе</a>
    <a href="#buy">Об оплате</a>
    <a href="#about">О нас</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="paper-window">
  <div id="paper-front">
    <div class="hamburger"><span></span></div>
    <div id="container">
      <section>
        <h1>Belzer Design</h1>
      </section>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```